# Debugging mDNS with Avahi across Linux and macOS

Tags: linux, osx, elementary-os, avahi, mdns

I have a network of elementary Loki (Ubuntu 16.04) computers at home which work great and can be accessed over mDNS/Avahi. `ping juggernaut.local` works as expected, and I can reach hosts both ways over mDNS.

I am the <s>proud</s> holder of three work laptops, one elementary Loki, the other two macOS. I'm using Synergy with TLS between them so I can control them all with one logical keyboard and mouse.

mDNS/Avahi don't appear to be working within the network I'm currently in, as I can't reach `*.local` between the laptops, which are named `sardaukar` and `arrakis`. I can reach the DNS names locally with `ping $(hostname).local`.

Is there a guide or some series of steps I can follow to diagnose why mDNS/Avahi isn't working? Are there firewall rules I need to allow? On my home network with Linux machines, it works without issues. I'd like to get it working here so that with Synergy, I can avoid specifying IP addresses directly and rather use the mDNS host names.

Comment: Can you please clarify: the *juggernaut.local* works in your ***home*** LAN, but the *sardaukar.local* and *arrakis.local* are hosts in your ***workplace*** LAN, where these names do not work for network connectivity?

Comment: They are always on the same network when I use them, things work on the home network and don't on the work network.

Answer (score 1):

For `.local` domains to work, the *mDNS* protocol ('multicast DNS') is applied. This protocol is specified in **[RFC6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762)**. It serves to resolve hostnames without a central DNS server, and it works through port 5353 (as compared to port 53 for DNS with a central name server).

It could be that the admins of your workplace network did setup in a way (maybe through virtual LANs, routers and firewall settings) which blocks mDNS traffic and doesn't allow to reach port 5353.